# Summing variable used in calculation after report is generated

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a report where a query returns a list of values which are being used in my detail band. A new value shows for each record like it should. I'm trying to sum up these values and then use them in a calculation on the same line. Heres an example:

```
Color       Fruit       # of fruit      Percent of total
--------------------------------------------------------
red         apple       4               57%
green       apple       3               43%

Total apples 7
```

The column being summed is the `# of fruit` or 3rd column. You can see the total at the end. Then the percent of total is the `# of fruit` for that row divided by the total. So for the first row it's `4 / 7` which equals `57%`.

The problem is that I can't get the total until all the fruit has been summed. But I need that total to be used on each row for the `Percent of total` column.

How do I create a variable to do this?